# ASP.NET return multiple list to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework and I am trying to return two list to one view.

So far I am able to return one list:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Data.ToList().Where(model => model.hidden == false).Where(model => model.collection == "Singles"));
}
```

I also need to return:

```
db.Data.ToList().Where(model => model.hidden == false).Where(model => model.collection == "Towns")
```

Comment: Just create a ViewModel that contains both lists and pass it to the View.

Comment: Can I see an example @raderick ?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a view model with 2 properties.

Assuming `db.Data` returns a collection of type `Data`

```
public clas ListViewModel
{
  public List<Data> SinglesData { set;get;}
  public List<Data> TownsData { set;get;}
}
```

Now use this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm=new ListViewModel();
  vm.SinglesData = db.Data
                     .Where(a=> a.hidden == false && a.collection == "Singles").ToList();
  vm.TownsData = db.Data
                   .Where(b=> b.hidden == false && b.collection == "Towns").ToList();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now make sure your view is strongly  typed to the new view model

```
@model ListViewModel
<h2>Singles Data </h1>
@foreach(var item in Model.SinglesData)
{
  <p>@item.SomeProperty</p>
}
<h2>Towns Data </h1>
@foreach(var item in Model.TownsData)
{
  <p>@item.SomeProperty</p>
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying `Data could not be found` in my new class

Comment: This is what db is `private Homefront db = new Homefront();`

Comment: What is the type of `db.Data.ToList()` ? or what was your view strongly typed to earlier ?

Comment: which comes from here `public class Homefront : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CentralParkPricing> Data { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Replace `Data` with `CentralParkPricing` in the ListViewModel view model. Ex : `public IEnumerable<CentralParkPricing> SinglesData`